# Going beyond something

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrase-meaning

> Some years ago, I started to go beyond being a simple user.

The meaning I want to give to the sentence is that after "some years ago" I'm not anymore a simple user but someone with a higher experience in the subject.

Is this sentence correct? What are alternatives to express the same?

Comment: Close voters, show yourself and say why do you want to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence makes sense. However, "A few years ago" is far more common than "Some years ago", although both are grammatical.

If you want to express this idea in a different, more idiomatic, way you could call your self **seasoned**.

Season (v): to mature, ripen, or condition by exposure to suitable conditions or treatment: a writer seasoned by experience.

It's a common idiom to call someone who has gained experienced a seasoned X, with "X" being their skill. In your case, "After a few years, I can call myself a seasoned user."

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically correct: yes.

Other ways to express the same thought:

"Some years ago, I started the process of becoming an advanced user."

"Some years ago, I began transitioning from a simple user to an advanced user."

"I began to advance beyond the stages of a simple user some years ago."

Answer (score 0):

- Some years ago I graduated from being a simple user to a more proficient/skilled/experienced one.
- Some years ago my skills matured beyond being a simple user/beginner to an intermediate user.
- Some years ago my expertise/proficiency achieved a fluency and maturity that only comes with experience.

I could go on...